# Python apscheduler variables from background scheduled task to bottle

Tags: python, bottle, apscheduler

I'm using bottle and apscheduler. I need to pass variables from background scheduler to main bottle-function.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from bottle import route, run, response


def tester():
"""
do some tests here
"""
  return testResultVariable

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(tester,'interval',seconds=30)
sched.start()
    

@route("/")
def root(testResultVariable):
  if testResultVariable == 1:
     response.status = 200
  else:
     response.status = 503


if __name__ == "__main__":
  run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

The main question is how to get "testResultVariable" variable from scheduled task?

This task must be running in the background and make some checks once per 30 secs, return variables to bottle/flask/whatever, and flask/bottle/etc must return http-code answer to user, based on this variable (testResultVariable). It must not be running only on user request - I need it to be running in the background every N-secs.

Comment: Hi, I am stuck on same issue with passing a variable after sched is called to other routes on my Flask app, how did you solve it?

Comment: @Oris via global vars

Answer (score 1):

Here's your original code, fixed and cleaned up to work with APScheduler. Tested locally and works.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from bottle import route, run, HTTPResponse

is_healthy = True

@route("/")
def root():
    return HTTPResponse(status = 200 if is_healthy else 503)

def update_health():
    global is_healthy
    if <your health check fails>:
        is_healthy = False

def main():
    sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
    sched.add_job(update_health, "interval", seconds=30)
    sched.start()

    run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I love `apscheduler`, but I recommend not using it for this. Instead, make a `/runtest` endpoint which runs your tests whenever it receives a POST request. Then simply hit it from an externally scheduled job (e.g. cron).

```
is_healthy = True

@route("/test", method="POST")
def run_test():
    global is_healthy
    if <your health check fails>:
        is_healthy = False

@route("/")
def root():
    if is_healthy:
        response.status = 200
    else:
        response.status = 503
```

I'd also recommend taking a step back and asking yourself if this is the appropriate design in the first place - could it be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: But the last sentence is "It must not be running only on user request - I need it to be running in the background every N-secs.", and it's the most important thing in the whole question.

Comment: And I cannot use external cron-scheduler or other software, because I need to store variables in the program itself to make other operations with it.

Comment: For now, I used global variables, but this is not the best practice, I suppose.

Comment: Why is it necessary that it run in the background?

Comment: It will be some kind of healthcheck that will always check the difference between two states of the side-program, and based on the difference of this states (not on the current state) return 200 or 503. I want to place it in the docker-image, and I don't want to run any kind of cron-app.